# UIImagePicker change color of searchbar placeholder text

Tags: ios

How to change the color of the placeholder text of an UIImagePicker? Preferably without using -appearance proxy. I am refering to the placeholder text in the search textfield. (Photos, People... text)
[image]

Alternatively how can I get the searchbar not to show up at all? The colors for the background were set via appearance proxy.

Comment: About which placeholder you are talking? Could you post a screenshot for expected result?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add some more detail or screenshots to get more views and answers

Comment: Please clarify the question by posting a screenshot or giving more explanation.

Comment: Added image and further clarification. I tried to enumerate the subviews of the picker but that doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 1):

You achieve placeholder color using this function.

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
]
```

Comment: This is not a search controller, it's a UIImagePickerView...